# Creating users in new Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to make a register view, where the users can register through email, password, username, phone number and city.

Here's the code for creating the users through email and password:

```
 @IBAction func Register(sender: AnyObject) {


   guard let email = EmailTextField.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) where !email.isEmpty else {
        print("Email is empty")
        return
             }

    guard let password = PasswordTextField.text where !password.isEmpty
        else {
    print("Password is empty")
        return
             }
    guard let repeatPassword = RePasswordTextField.text where !repeatPassword.isEmpty
        else {
             print("Repeat Password is empty")
            return
             }

    guard password == repeatPassword else {
    print("Password does not match")
        return
    }

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(EmailTextField.text!, password: PasswordTextField.text!, completion: { user, error in
        if let error = error {
        print(error)
        } else {
            if let user = user {
            print(user)
            }
        }

    })
}
```

the question is how can I add the other values like username to firebase dashboard?

in the previous version of firebase I was creating a dictionary then use the setValue function!
But in the new firebase how can I do that?

Comment: Its still the same read :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data Which firebase version are you working with?

Comment: @ Dravidian The latest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing data in user's respective `uid`

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()  //Global Variable
 ... 
 ...
 @IBAction func Register(sender: AnyObject) {


guard let email = EmailTextField.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) where !email.isEmpty else {
    print("Email is empty")
    return
         }

guard let password = PasswordTextField.text where !password.isEmpty
    else {
print("Password is empty")
    return
         }
guard let repeatPassword = RePasswordTextField.text where !repeatPassword.isEmpty
    else {
         print("Repeat Password is empty")
        return
         }

guard password == repeatPassword else {
print("Password does not match")
    return
}

FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(EmailTextField.text!, password: PasswordTextField.text!, completion: { user, error in
    if let error = error {
    print(error)
    } else {
        ref.child("UserProfile").child(user!.uid).setValue([
                    "username" : usernameTextField.text!,    //Or whatever way you are extracting these information
                    "phoneNumber" : phoneNumberTextField.text!,     //Or whatever way you are extracting these information
                    "city" : cityTextField.text!       //Or whatever way you are extracting these information
                    ])
     }
  })
}
```

Your JSON tree will look something like this :-

```
{UserProfile : {
   user_ID_1 :{
          userName : "Tim",
          phoneNumber : +1(23)....,
          city : "Los Angeles"    
               }

   user_ID_2 :{
          userName : "Hnery",
          phoneNumber : +1(073)....,
          city : "New York"    
               }
       }
}
```

Comment: Should I add those lines of codes inside the button?

Comment: @ Dravidian Thanks.